# How can I run a small command in a concourse pipeline?

Tags: continuous-integration, concourse

I basically want to run the npm install and grunt build command within the newly added repo.

```
        inputs:
          - name: repo

          - path:
        run:
          path: repo/
          args:
          - npm install
          - grunt build
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`path:` refers to the path in the container to the binary / script to execute.

Check out this example on the **Tasks** documentation here : https://concourse-ci.org/tasks.html#task-environment

```
run:
  path: sh
  args:
  - -exc
  - |
    whoami
    env
```

`sh` is the program to execute, and `args` are passed to the `sh` program

Comment: how do you run this within "do" ? 

```on_failure:
      do:  
      - run:
        path: sh
        args:
        - -exc
        - |
          whoami
          env``` 

doesn't validate for example. 

I guess my syntax is wrong somehow.

Answer (score 0):

slight variation of Topher Bullock's answer

```
run:
  path: sh
  args:
  - -exc
  - whoami && env
```

which will run `env` if only `whoami` doesn't return error

This will run `env` even if `whoami` fails.

```
run:
  path: sh
  args:
  - -exc
  - whoami || env
```

Comment: Do you mean "This will run `env` **only** if `whoami` fails"?